# Sql Create useraccounts through vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to create sql user accounts through vb.net. I am checking if the users are already present if not then create accounts. I have below code which is not throwing an error but it is not creating accounts.I checked through management studio those accounts are not present there but if I use the same query in management studio it is creating user accounts under security/Logic folder. Need some help to fix the problem

```
Private Function createUser(ByVal UserName, ByVal Password)
    Dim crUser As Boolean
    Try
        Dim myconn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Server=DEVxyz-DC1\TESTSQL;uid=sa;pwd=test12345!#%")
        Dim myreader As SqlDataReader
        Dim result As Object
        Dim command As String
        myconn.Open()
        Try
            ' Dim sqlstring As String = "IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * from sys.server_principals WHERE name=N'" & UserName & ") CREATE LOGIN[" & UserName & "] WITH PASSWORD=N'" & Password & "',DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], CHECK_EXPIRATION=ON,CHECK_POLICY=ON"
            Dim mycommand As SqlCommand
            mycommand = myconn.CreateCommand
            Command = "SELECT * from sys.server_principals WHERE name=N'" + UserName + "'"
            mycommand.CommandText = (command)
            myreader = mycommand.ExecuteReader()


            If myreader.HasRows Then
                Do While myreader.Read()
                    MessageBox.Show("Records Found,please enter another user name ")

                Loop
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Records Not Found")
                'Create user accounts
                myreader.Close()
                command = "CREATE LOGIN[" + UserName + "] WITH PASSWORD=N'" + Password + "',DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], CHECK_EXPIRATION=ON,CHECK_POLICY=ON"
                Try
                    myreader = mycommand.ExecuteReader()
                Catch y As SqlException
                    MessageBox.Show(y.ToString())
                End Try

            End If

            myreader.Close()

            ' mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Catch ep As SqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ep.ToString)
        End Try

        myconn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)

    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: You have forgotten to set the SqlCommand.CommandText with the sql that create your user. You are running your first command two times.

Comment: Yep I realized that and posted a answer as well. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have added below statement and it worked
mycommand.CommandText = (command)

Private Function createUser(ByVal UserName, ByVal Password)
    Dim crUser As Boolean
    Try
        Dim myconn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Server=DEVxyz-DC1\TESTSQL;uid=sa;pwd=test12345!#%")
        Dim myreader As SqlDataReader
        Dim result As Object
        Dim command As String
        myconn.Open()
        Try
            ' Dim sqlstring As String = "IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * from sys.server_principals WHERE name=N'" & UserName & ") CREATE LOGIN[" & UserName & "] WITH PASSWORD=N'" & Password & "',DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], CHECK_EXPIRATION=ON,CHECK_POLICY=ON"
            Dim mycommand As SqlCommand
            mycommand = myconn.CreateCommand
            Command = "SELECT * from sys.server_principals WHERE name=N'" + UserName + "'"
            mycommand.CommandText = (command)
            myreader = mycommand.ExecuteReader()

```
        If myreader.HasRows Then
            Do While myreader.Read()
                MessageBox.Show("Records Found,please enter another user name ")

            Loop
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Records Not Found")
            'Create user accounts
            myreader.Close()
            command = "CREATE LOGIN[" + UserName + "] WITH PASSWORD=N'" + Password + "',DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], CHECK_EXPIRATION=ON,CHECK_POLICY=ON"
            Try
                mycommand.CommandText = (command)
                myreader = mycommand.ExecuteReader()
            Catch y As SqlException
                MessageBox.Show(y.ToString())
            End Try

        End If

        myreader.Close()

        ' mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch ep As SqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ep.ToString)
    End Try

    myconn.Close()

Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)

End Try
```

End Function